# excel formula - Mid Search Or

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I had set a formula which tend to find and extract the "ABC" with ending of SPACE.

Formula - `=MID(C2902,SEARCH("ABC",C2902),SEARCH(" ",C2902)-SEARCH("ABC",C2902))`

Here are some example:

```
TTABC tomorrow.txt (the ABC being extracted)
BE ABC 2more dot.txt (the ABC being extracted)
```

Now I realize from file are ABC.txt then the above formula will return #VALUE in the result cell, therefore I wonder if possible to add **OR operator** into the SEARCH part to become similar formula like this - `=MID(C2902,SEARCH("ABC",C2902),SEARCH(" " | ".",C2902)-SEARCH("ABC",C2902))`?

Thanks

JC

Comment: It looks like you're basically just returning ABC if it's found in the cell with a space or full stop after it, in which case: `=IF(COUNT(SEARCH("ABC"&{" ","."},E13)),"ABC","")` should do.

Comment: @Rory : could you add that as an answer?

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for the feedback:

Maybe I'm not explaining that clear and here let me try to make it more clear:

I"m currently using the formula 
=MID(C2904,SEARCH("ABC",C2904),SEARCH({" ","."},C2904)-SEARCH("ABC",C2904))

Which to check the cell C2904 if it contains "ABC", if it do then I will have to extract string "ABC-123", now the string in the cell can be:
TT ABC-123 befeee.txt
bwaste ABC-123.txt
I want to extract the string start from ABC and end with either " " or "."

Thanks

JC